How to get the total addition/reduction count shown on GitHub query result?
I can get the list of PRs easily with query like
is:pr is:merged base:master repo:offa/android-foss  merged:>2023-07-01 

As you can see on e.g. this result, it is not showing the total lines of code added or removed:

I need to go into each PR to see the number e.g.:

It is possible to show the total addition and deletion of lines of code on the query result?
